# How to enable standard horizontal window menu bar in KDE plasma?

Tags: menu, plasma5

Distro: Fedora 32.

I tried Application Style module: But it only has "Application style" and "Window decorations". I guess there should be a Widget Style module in the list as well?

I have a hamburger button [image] in my window title bars which contains the menu items for the application.

Can I get my menu bar back (like File Edit View Tools etc)?
Desktop publishing and many utilities are tough without a horizontal, wide open menu bar.

Comment: What's your distro? Please try this: Go to System settings -> Application style -> Widget style -> Fine tuning, and change the Menubar style to something different than what's specified there.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Its Fedora 32 and Application Style module has only "Application style" and "Window decorations" :(

Comment: I've installed Fedora 32 using default settings and I cannot reproduce this bug. It looks like you're using either a custom widget style or custom decoration style.  Please try reverting your changes.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks Ill get back to this post asap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Window Decorations** system settings and click the **Titlebar Buttons** tab.

Remove the hamburger icon from the titlebar.

Menu bar comes back.

Comment: No it doesn't work for KDE neon 5.27.8.